# Make special td that breaks bounds of table

Tags: html, css

Suppose I want to create a table in which some rows have a border that breaks the bounds of the table - like so.

```
 +-+-+-+
 +-+-+-+
|+-+-+-+| 
 +-+-+-+
```

How would I do that?

I've tried `outline` and `outline-offset`, but the latter is not supported for IE.

Comment: I think you're going to have to put a `<div>` in the table cell and position it so that it overflows the cell.

Comment: in the first and last ones?

Comment: Yeah. Hold on...let me see if I can do up a proof of concept. Edit: Posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use some divs and overflow the table cell like so:

https://jsbin.com/recexe/edit?html,css,output

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.ol {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px;
}

.or {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="ol"></div></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><div class="or"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: hmm close, (wasn't sure how to communicate this earlier), but what if I wanted the top and bottom border of the div to show, without making it look like the div was there? (as well as the side).

Comment: @praks5432 I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. You can use borders on the div instead of a background color. You can add them to top/bottom/left/right whatever you want or use several divs if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they work on tables, but have a look at first-child nth-child and last-child in CSS attributes.

It would be:

**tr:nth-child(6)**

And **width:108%;** for a wider row.

Comment: That'll help you target the cells but won't help you break the bounds.

Comment: Did you try your `width:108%` trick? You can't have some rows wider than others. Tables don't work like that.